# maven does not print name of tested class; replaces class name with TestSuite

Tags: eclipse, maven, automated-tests, testng

I'm running this project with testNG, i get the test result(successful one) as

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.13.1
Success!!
Dec 07, 2017 4:44:06 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
PASSED: begin
PASSED: google

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

But when running as Maven test, it doesn't print the name of passed test cases(or any test). It just gives number of tests run. I want the passed cases to be printed here as well.

P.S. - Class is in src/test/java. Tried changing it to  src/main/java as suggested in one of issue. but maven skipped the tests altogether in that way as Surefire-plugin runs all tests that are in test source directory src/test/java.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenFrstProj 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MavenFrstProj ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
C:\Users\Shrikanth\workspace\MavenFrstProj\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ 
MavenFrstProj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) 
@ MavenFrstProj ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
C:\Users\Shrikanth\workspace\MavenFrstProj\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 
MavenFrstProj ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ MavenFrstProj --
-
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
Success!!
Dec 07, 2017 4:45:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.017 
s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
---
[INFO] Total time: 11.972 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-07T16:46:02+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/178M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note : Also checking the xml report(TestSuite) generated in target/surefire-reports, it replaces class name as TestSuite and in console output it prints Running TestSuite instead of Running <*classname*>. May be thats the root, but not sure. How do I fix it. Please help!

Comment: Why are you using TestSuites...

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

```
"**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
"**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
"**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
"**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
```

Make sure your test class names follow this pattern otherwise , add each class inclusively in pom.xml

Comment: Changed class name to Test*, added classpath in pom.xml. But nothing happens still.